# Vscode autocomplete

Tags: vscode-snippets

When typing:
`variable.cont`
Then output:
`const variable =`

It is possible in vscode?

I tried code snippet like this:

```json
"const": {
    "prefix": "const",
    "body": "const ${1:va} = ${2:null}",
    "description": "quick create const snippets"
  },
```

But when I declare a variable, my step is:

1. the variable name
2. determine using `const` or `let`
3. initial value

So, I need a better way to help me to declare different variables.